# is V8 thread-safe at the moment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, v8

I was finally picking v8 as the scripting engine for my application when I realized that I missed an important spot: concurrency.

I decided to go with v8 instead of lua because of a couple of key factors, but apparently I can't write thread safe code or a multithreaded task in general, with v8.

On the official docs I found no reference to the concurrent features of v8, they describe the GC, that v8 is written in C++, it's supporting a lot of platforms, and so on, but nothing about threading on both the wiki and the official documentation for embedding v8 inside a C++ application.

Question: how I should be thinking about v8 ? I have to expose my application as a set of single-threaded/thread-safe functions right from C++ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V8 is not thread safe, but that doesn't mean you can't use it in a threaded environment. The only stipulation for doing so is using V8's `Locker` object, whenever you access any V8 related stuff.

Doing so is really simple, just create a new instance of `v8::Locker` and then when you're done with whatever action you were doing in V8, create an instance of `v8::Unlocker`

In my experience with V8's documentation...it royally sucks and it seems (in my use anyway) the best way to learn how to use it was trial and error.

EDIT:  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7921673/342763) answer here explains multithreaded use of V8 better than I did:

Comment: both `Isolate` and `Locker` sound like a mutex from C/C++, but I don't get 1 thing, how to fire up multiple threads ? in the linked answer there is a link that says that v8 only works on 1 thread at a time, is it true for any scenario inside v8 ?

Comment: As far as I know yes that is true, V8 can only be running on one thread a time.

Though to clairfy the first part of your comment, an `Isolate` is basically an clean instance of V8. You create a new `Isolate` to separate execution of differnet scripts. If anything `Locker` is more akin to a mutex than an `Isolate` is.